# Package installation

Tags: package

When i am trying to install an unmanaged-package it gives me following error:- [image: "Aura integration service error"]

I can't identify the cause of error

Comment: can you post package url ?

Comment: It's an unmanaged-package so it would not be possible for me to share the url.

Comment: Have you tried https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206360&language=en_US (I know it's aimed at AppExchange packages, but worth a try)

Comment: There's probably something wrong in the package or in the org you're installing it from. I would raise a support ticket for this.